# sql query to fetch the third highest sale grouped by sales

Tags: mysql, sql

Fetch the third highest sale amount from the table (group by sale amount) in MySQL

```
 select Top 3 * from t1 group by sale_Amnt 

|Id|product_name|product_group    |sale_Amnt(INR)
------------------------------------------------
 1|  p1       |   Cosmetic       |4485
 2|  p2       |   Cosmetic       |8525
 3|  p3       |   Health         |12589
 4|  p4       |   Health         |8525
 5|  p5       |   Home Appliances|9858
 6|  p6       |   Home Appliances|12589
```

Expected output

```
|Id|product_name|product_group    |sale_Amnt(INR)
------------------------------------------------
 2|  p2       |   Cosmetic       |8525
 4|  p4       |   Health         |8525`
```

Comment: You should start with the duplicate link, try a query, and then if you get stuck come back here for help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  MySQL is not consistent with the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed duplicate is a misunderstanding of the question.  This question appears to be looking for the third highest value overall, but taking duplicates into account.

You can get the third row using `offset`/`fetch` in SQL Server:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sale_amount = (select t2.sale_amount
                       from t t2
                       group by t2.sale_amount
                       order by t2.sale_amount desc
                       offset 2 fetch first 1 row only
                      );
```

In MySQL, that would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sale_amount = (select t2.sale_amount
                       from t t2
                       group by t2.sale_amount
                       order by t2.sale_amount desc
                       limit 1 offset 2
                      );
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking at

Comment: Does this query run on MySQL server?

Comment: @BLPraveen . . . It will if you use `limit` instead of `offset/fetch`.

Comment: Is there another way without using limit

Comment: @BLPraveen . . . Why are you asking?  Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: In interview they asked to try without using limit

Comment: @BLPraveen . . . You should ask another question.  This answers the question you did ask.  Changing the question can invalidate answers, which draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT * FROM `sale_amnt` ORDER BY `sale_Amnt` DESC LIMIT 2,1
```